# Plot more than 3 words per topic for STM?

Tags: r, plot, nlp

Is it possible to plot more than 3 words for each topic using the STM package?

```
topic.count <- 10
model.stm <- stm(stm_1$documents, stm_1$vocab, K = topic.count, data = stm_1$meta, 
init.type = "Spectral")
```

With "plot, type = "summary", I get 3 words per topic in a plot

```
plot(model.stm, type = "summary", text.cex = 1)
```

With "labelTopics", I get 7 words per topic under "Highest Prob" as a list

```
labelTopics(model.stm)
```

Is there a way to plot 4 or 5 words instead of having the default 3 like the below code?

```
plot(model.stm, type = "summary", text.cex = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - by setting `n`.  Example:

```r
library("stm")
## stm v1.3.6 successfully loaded. See ?stm for help. 
##  Papers, resources, and other materials at structuraltopicmodel.com

plot(gadarianFit, type = "summary", text.cex = 0.9, n = 5)
```

[image]